# ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY ORDER BY IN Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, window-functions

I have populated tables and I have come up with the SQL script using ROW_NUMBER to obtain my desired result set. The question is how to convert the script to EF statement.

[image: Schema and Values]

[image: Desired Result Set]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from room in context.Rooms
let firstGuest = room.Guests
                     .OrderBy(x => x.CheckInDate)
                     .FirstOrDefault()
select new 
{ 
    RoomName = room.Name, 
    GuestName = firstGuest.GuestName,
    CheckInDate = firstGuest.CheckInDate
};
```

Entity Framework does not support `PARTITION BY` and will instead, most likely generate the query using `CROSS APPLY` instead.

Comment: Thanks bro! I didn't realize I don't need to use join explicitly